# SSRS 2014 remote authentication

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, reportmanager, ssrs-2014

I have an instance of SSRS 2014 running on Windows Server 2012r2.
from the server everything looking good, I can deploy reports and connecting to ReportServer succesfuly.

But in my ASP.Net app when I try to generate report, i get "logon prompt".
The service set by domain user account, this user has premmision in reportServer DB and also in report manager URL - Site Setting and Home folder

I tried to set in the "Site Setting" premissions for "Everyone" and "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" but no change.

Do I need to set anonymous authentication ?
there is way to set authentication just to user defined through the app?

Thanks